# Failure in allocating contiguous memory allocation using calloc

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I'm running attached code in 64-bit system, so I expect for this buffer bytes (21B), I'd be able to allocate memory, but calloc fails to do that and so it returns a NULL pointer. For smaller buffer bytes like 20 B, it will be fine but breaks at 21 B and as I checked for different machines, this breaking point can vary. I just need to know what should I check in that system that it's inhibiting me from this memory allocation?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) 
{
   size_t bufferBytes = 21000000000;
  //  size_t bufferBytes = 20000000000;
  // Use words instead of bytes to ensure 8-byte alignment.
    size_t bufferWords = bufferBytes / 8;
    auto m_buffer      = reinterpret_cast<char *>(calloc(bufferWords, 8));
    if(m_buffer==NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"Not a valid pointer"<<std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested in why you feel the need to allocate that much memory? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: And do your system even have that amount of available virtual memory? Remember, even on a system with a lot of memory, your program is not alone, it has to share the memory with other processes.

Comment: There's generally no way to know. Even if you had something to ask for the amount of free space, it's subject to a race condition--some other program could allocate space in the mean time, so your allocation could fail. Worse, you could be running on Linux so the allocation might succeed--but when/if you try to use that space, the OOMKiller kills your programs.

Comment: reinterpret_cast and calloc are usually code smells in C++. And you still include a lot of "C" header files. Is this new code? If so then there are better ways like using `std::vector<std::string>` and use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. By now I am curious where you are learning C++ from because it seems to be an outdated (almost antique) source. If you need this access to this much data considere a memory mapped file instead.

Comment: `Use words instead of bytes to ensure 8-byte alignment`. The `calloc` function returns a block of memory suitably aligned for any object type. The size of the elements you provide makes zero difference.

Comment: 1. `void*` to `char*` can be cast with `static_cast`. 2. Prefer `auto*` for pointers. Once you want to use `const auto` you might unexpectedly make `const` a pointer not a pointee.

Comment: It might be fun, just for the sake of learning/exploration, to see how much memory you can allocate by allocating multiple smaller chunks of various sizes, as opposed to one single giant allocation.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm aware that the style is outdated, and I know there will be a more modern way to handle that, It's just a piece of code I extracted from an old repository, so I can't change things fundamentally.

Comment: @MA19 Ok I know these things happen too (might have been worth mentioning), so I hope I didn't offend you (just my passion about C++ code quality). Happy refactoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic problem of "how much memory can I allocate with `malloc`" depends on multiple factors such as your OS, your library implementation of `malloc`/`calloc` and how much RAM you have.

Generally, however, for such huge allocations, library implementations bypass the heap entirely and go straight for the OS services (`mmap` on Linux, `VirtualAlloc` on Windows). It is up to the OS to decide what limit they impose on these allocations. For example, my Windows machine tops out at ~52GB for a single `calloc` (with 16GB of physical RAM), but this limit is dynamic (if RAM is heavily used by various processes, this limit will be lower).

The virtual address space of a 64-bit systems is (for now) really big. However, this is not true for the physical address space, where most consumer computers have 8-32GB of RAM.

When you demand such a large allocation, your OS doesn't actually reserve any physical memory for you, but instead only marks a certain area in your virtual address space as usable. When you try to access that memory, that's when the OS will actually allocate it for you. You can see this by checking your process in the Task Manager (or `htop` on Linux). Add a `while(1);` at the very end of the program and you will see that your program barely uses any memory.

Once you start using more memory than you actually have RAM, the OS will start swapping it to disk (making your computer run very slowly), so that it can make space in RAM. However, it can only do this up to a certain point. It can't use hundreds of gigabytes on your hard drive for swap. The OS will therefore top out at a certain size (see [setrlimit](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) on Linux), so that it doesn't promise you memory that it might not be able to give you.

Comment: On Linux, running `free -h` prints out 15 G for `Mem` and 4.0 G for `Swap`. So, I have 16 G physical ram like in your system. Does it really make sense to fail 21 G of memory allocation? as You mentioned that your system fails for around 52 G, I'm still half of this amount. I know it varies system by system for so many reasons but does half make sense?

Comment: I have another question as well. You mentioned that "When you demand such a large allocation, your OS doesn't actually reserve any physical memory for you, but instead only marks a certain area in your virtual address space as usable" and considering that "the virtual address space of a 64-bit systems is (for now) really big" , why 21 G is big enough for my system to be allocated?